# Laravel: Unknown column when using alias in DB::raw()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I'm running the following SQL in Laravel:

```
$sql = 'SELECT university.id, university.name, MAX(uni_score) AS score
FROM (SELECT uni_id, place AS uni_score FROM ranking) AS tmp
LEFT JOIN university ON university.id = tmp.uni_id
ORDER BY score';

$result = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
```

However the code throws this error:

**Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'uni_score' in 'field list'**.

`uni_score` is an alias for `place` field in `ranking` table. The query above works fine when ran directly in phpMyAdmin.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to see what the exact query Laravel is running by using this: `$queries = DB::getQueryLog();` `$last_query = end($queries);` `dd($last_query);` See if there's something unexpected happening.

Comment: The problem is I cannot do that because the query gets aborted due to the error thrown. I'm pretty sure this is somehow Laravel's query builder issue, not a real SQL error. I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Oh right, that would happen. Hmm. The only other thing I can think of is changing your `DB::select(...)` statement to `DB::connection("connection_name")->select(DB::raw($sql));`, as that's how I have all of my `DB::raw()` statements and it's the only difference I can see.

Comment: Didn't think this would help but tried anyway. No luck.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't either. Would only make sense for multiple database connections, but worth a shot. Last thing to try, hybridize your select. Use `Model::select()` where you can, and `DB::raw()` where the Query Builder wouldn't work.

Comment: Did you try running this against your database without using Laravel? Is ranking and university linked by a FK?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `DB::statement($query);` method.